# How to configure git to include my name in commits

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have set up my name and email as follows

```
git config --global user.name myname
```

However, when I run git log after commit, it shows unknown instead of myname:

```
Author: unknown <myname@mybox.mycompany.com>
```

What should I do to have my name listed by log command?

Edit: the output of config -l is as follows:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
gui.recentrepo=C:/Git/MyProject
core.editor='C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.autocrlf=false
user.name=myalias
user.email=myalias@MYDOMAIN.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@git:myproject.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Edit: started a bounty.

Edit 2: In fact, git commit from command line was including my name, but TortoiseGit failed to do so. So this is a problem with TortoiseGit.

Comment: Are you looking at commits you made before you ran `git config`?

Comment: @jamessan: no, I just did another test commit, and git log still shows  unknown for that last one

Comment: Please paste the output of `git config -l` If you have set up your config by editing config files, you may have looked in the wrong place. Also, it sounds like your email is configured but the name is not, correct? Also, how are you committing? Not doing anything like git commit -C HEAD That would use old info.

Comment: @ArneLund - You didn't even talk about TortoiseGit before. Talk about giving all the info when people have been asking for it...

Comment: @manojlds: my bad, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an empty dir with no parent being a git-repository and cd there. Execute the following commands.

```
git init .
touch foo
git add foo
git commit -m "initial"
git log
git config -l
```

Please provide the output of `git log` and `git config -l` of these two calls.

Comment: In fact, git commit from command line was including my name, but TortoiseGit failed to do so. Your answer did help me, thanks!

Comment: If you're using Tortoise Git, you might like Git Extensions. You'll probably have less issues with it too. Just saying this because you seem to prefer a GUI and I have not had any issues with changing my name on Git Extenstions (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/)

Comment: +1 for @carleeto recommendation of Git Extensions.  The project web site (http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) tends to be more up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

the `git config --global user.name myname` will only take effect with commits done after this change.

Commits pushed before you changed the .gitconfig will keep the old value of `user.name`

Have you checked with recently done commits?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have your user name set (to "unknown") in your local `.git/config`? That would override the global setting.

Comment: no, if I run git config user.name without --global flag, it still returns myname

Answer (score 3):

Verify that that the username is not overriden ( to unknown ) in GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_NAME environment variables and also the local `.git/config`

If that is not the case, make sure you are committing and not just seeing old log of commits that were done before you set the username. ( one mistake people do is to try commit without staging files etc.)

Comment: my .git/config file does not have the entries you've mentioned. I did a new commit after setting my user name.

Comment: @ArneLund - And the commit did not have your name again when you see it in git log?

Comment: exactly. I just committed again, same thing.

Comment: @ArneLund:  And what about the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` environment variable?  What is the output of running `echo "${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME}"`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's is [how you can change your history](https://serverfault.com/questions/12373/how-do-i-edit-gits-history-to-correct-an-incorrect-email-address-name/13162#13162). 
You should probably also check your .mailmap file to see if there are any conflicting settings there.